# Contact us link at the bottom is screwed in GMail

Tags: bug, status-completed

The mailto:link at the bottom of the page is interpreted wrongly by GMail -- it actually opens mail with "team meta.pm@stackexchange.com" instead of "team+meta.pm@stackexchange.com"

I'm not sure whether it should be addressed to SE team or more to Google but maybe there's tweak which would make it work.

Comment: This should be fixed when we next build (i.e. when the number bottom-right is something other than 2011.4.19.3)

Comment: Indeed, works well at the moment. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I can't reproduce this. When I click the link I get a mail correctly composed to

> team+meta.pm@stackexchange.com

Note that + is indeed a valid URL character, but now that I think about this -- maybe you're right.

a `+` typically means "space" in a URL, e.g.

`http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java+sorting`

I don't really think of a mailto: as a URL, but perhaps it is?

[image]

Comment: The difference might be using FF 3.6.16 which asks me about mail client I want to use. The default one is Outlook but I choose GMail. Anyway, it seems you guys have already figured it out.